# How to export and use global variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a Flutter App and I need a global http client with some setup.

Flutter: 1.5.4
Dart: 2.3.2

```dart
// utils/http.dart

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cookie_jar/cookie_jar.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Dio http = Dio();

void main() async {
  // Save cookies to cookie jar.
  Directory appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  http.interceptors.add(CookieManager(PersistCookieJar(dir: appDir.path)));
}
```

```dart
// main.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'app.dart';

import 'utils/http.dart';

void main() {
  print(http.interceptors); // returns []
  runApp(App());
}
```

I expect that `main` function in http should be automatically executed.

Comment: You can't automatically invoke code by `import`ing it.  If you want to do some initialization, you'll need to put that code in a function and then call it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution to this is to wrap it in a Widget and place that widget in the Widget Tree. High up in the tree, so that it's sort of global. It's called "lifing state up".

The out of box solution of Flutter for such things is `InheritedWidget`. It's worth looking at and understand because most 3rd-party solutions rely on it.

To make life a tad easier, however, I use [pacakge:provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). Code would look like so:

### Creating

```dart
Provider<Dio>(
  builder: (_) => Dio(),
  child: MaterialApp(/*...*/)
);
```

### Consuming

later in the widget tree:

```dart
Consumer<Dio>(
  builder: (ctx, dio, _) {
    // widget builder method
    debugPrint('Dio instance: ${dio}');
    return Container();
  }
);
```

Comment: Could you add some example on how to use it for example if i have two classes that should use the http client, how to import it?

Comment: The package's github page has one: https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/blob/master/packages/provider/example/lib/main.dart